# Making Scale Bar in ArcMap end in zeros?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, scale-bar

I need my the last scale number to show as 900 instead of 870, but can't find the right way to achieve this in ArcMap.  I've tried many of the options in the Properties of my scale bar in ArcMap to change this, but to no avail.

Is this possible, to determine what the last number will show as, or to even have numbers that only end in zeros on my scale? (i.e. 100, 300, 900)

Comment: Show up as 900 where in ArcMap? Could you add a screenshot?

Comment: Unless I misunderstand,  once you add the scale bar in layout view all you need to do is click it and drag it (the blue box) out to the number you wish.  You can right click to do other things like set the break points of the scale, etc...

Comment: Thanks pal!  That was way too easy.  I remember now that we went over this in a lecture, but I guess with so many details I had forgotten.

Answer (score 4):

You can easily achieve this without guessing and checking by right clicking your scale bar and finding the "When resizing" option.  Make sure it is set to "Adjust width" and then change the division value to whatever you want.  In addition, if you want your map to be at a specific ratio (i.e. 1 inch = 3000 ft), then you will need to set your map scale to "1:3000 * 12" (1:36000) and make the division value 3000. Of course, this calculation pertains to units of feet.  You would have to come up with the correct conversion for whichever map unit your coordinate system uses.

Using this technique, figure out how many division values you need to make the last number show up as desired.

[image]