# Making Scale Bar end in zeros for Data Driven Pages?

Tags: arcmap, data-driven-pages, scale-bar

This is related to [Making Scale Bar in ArcMap end in zeros?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/226979)

I want the scale bar to end in round numbers continually in data driven pages without overrunning the data frame. With the Adjust width setting, I get the round numbers and with the adjust division value, I get crazy numbers. I did see on the data driven pages setup page (extent), best fit option the ability to round scale to the nearest but its rather finicky and I can't find any documentation on how to get it to relate to the map scale bar.

See picture below, but I would prefer the miles to end in a whole number and the feet to end in 1000. The polygons that are driving the data driven pages are municipalities and range in size from small to large.

I'm using ArcMap 10.5

[image]